# How can I create a new Object based on a Object with Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have one global saved array with a catalog, and a list of items that the user saved for him.
I need to create a new array of Objects (with arrays) with only the items saved by the client. 
I'm using javascript in react-native, but i think that javascript will be as global as it can be.

I already have filtered the 'categories' successfully and also filtered figures with array.map and array.filter, but i really need the basic structure formed again, so i can reuse a component to render the list.

The global array

```
const catalog = [
    {
        title: "Masculine T-Shirts 2017",
        code:"1101",
        page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1101/",
        data: [[
            {
                code:"1101-1",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 1",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1101/product/1101-1/",
                description:"description of product 1",
             },
             {
                code:"1101-2",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 2",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1101/product/1101-2/",
                description:"description of product 2",
             },
             {
                code:"1101-3",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 3",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1101/product/1101-3/",
                description:"description of product 3",
             }
        ]]
    },
    {
        title: "Masculine T-Shirts 2018",
        code:"1203",
        page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1203/",
        data: [[
            {
                code:"1203-1",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 1",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1203/product/1203-1/",
                description:"description of product 1",
             },
             {
                code:"1203-2",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 2",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1203/product/1203-2/",
                description:"description of product 2",
             },
             {
                code:"1203-3",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 3",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1203/product/1203-3/",
                description:"description of product 3",
             },
             {
                code:"1203-4",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 4",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1203/product/1203-4/",
                description:"description of product 4",
             }
        ]]
    },
    {
        title: "Masculine socks 2018",
        code:"1304",
        page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1304/",
        data: [[
            {
                code:"1304-1",
                name:"Masculine socks product 1",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1304/product/1304-1/",
                description:"description of socks product 1",
             },
             {
                code:"1304-2",
                name:"Masculine socks product 2",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1304/product/1304-2/",
                description:"description of socks product 2",
             }
        ]]
    },
]
```

The user saved list:

```
SavedList = ["1304-2","1101-3","1304-2"];
```

i need the returned array to be filtered, but in the same form of the original array, example:

```
savedCatalog = [
    {
        title: "Masculine T-Shirts 2017",
        code:"1101",
        page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1101/",
        data: [[
             {
                code:"1101-3",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 3",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1101/product/1101-3/",
                description:"description of product 3",
             }
        ]]
    },
    {
        title: "Masculine socks 2018",
        code:"1304",
        page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1304/",
        data: [[
            {
                code:"1304-1",
                name:"Masculine socks product 1",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1304/product/1304-1/",
                description:"description of socks product 1",
             },
             {
                code:"1304-2",
                name:"Masculine socks product 2",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1304/product/1304-2/",
                description:"description of socks product 2",
             }
        ]]
    },
]
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `data` is a two-dimensional array?

Comment: what's with `data: [[ ... ]]` ?  Is that always a single element wrapping an array?

Comment: because of react-native SectionList, to proper render the items inside the sections, the solution was create one array inside an array, in that way sectionlist render the data one-way to display it. there is another way to to this, but this way the FlatList  inside the SectionList renders a way faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do this which as you thought uses map and filter.  A new catalog item is constructed using Object.assign (so we don't directly change what's in the catalog constant) which has only the searched items, and then we filter the newly constructed catalog items for those that have more than zero search results.

```js
const catalog = [
    {
        title: "Masculine T-Shirts 2017",
        code:"1101",
        page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1101/",
        data: [[
            {
                code:"1101-1",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 1",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1101/product/1101-1/",
                description:"description of product 1",
             },
             {
                code:"1101-2",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 2",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1101/product/1101-2/",
                description:"description of product 2",
             },
             {
                code:"1101-3",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 3",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1101/product/1101-3/",
                description:"description of product 3",
             }
        ]]
    },
    {
        title: "Masculine T-Shirts 2018",
        code:"1203",
        page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1203/",
        data: [[
            {
                code:"1203-1",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 1",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1203/product/1203-1/",
                description:"description of product 1",
             },
             {
                code:"1203-2",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 2",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1203/product/1203-2/",
                description:"description of product 2",
             },
             {
                code:"1203-3",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 3",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1203/product/1203-3/",
                description:"description of product 3",
             },
             {
                code:"1203-4",
                name:"Masculine T-Shirt product 4",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1203/product/1203-4/",
                description:"description of product 4",
             }
        ]]
    },
    {
        title: "Masculine socks 2018",
        code:"1304",
        page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1304/",
        data: [[
            {
                code:"1304-1",
                name:"Masculine socks product 1",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1304/product/1304-1/",
                description:"description of socks product 1",
             },
             {
                code:"1304-2",
                name:"Masculine socks product 2",
                page:"http://www.blablabla.com/catalog/1304/product/1304-2/",
                description:"description of socks product 2",
             }
        ]]
    },
]

let savedList = ["1304-2","1101-3","1304-1"];

let savedCatalog = catalog.map(item =>
  Object.assign({}, item, {data: [
    item.data[0].filter(dat => savedList.includes(dat.code))
  ]})
).filter(item => item.data[0].length);

console.log(savedCatalog);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @James. Worked right away!
I've almost lost my mind on this problem! Thank you!